# WordPress foreach loop - order taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have standard WordPress taxonomies (category) is there any way to order them in `foreach` loop? For example by `name & desc`?

Comment: Related Question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/14306/17305

Comment: So you have a list of taxonomy you want to be ordered ASC? Personally, i'd get the data into an array and manipulate it as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the standard get_categories function, like so:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'hide_empty' => 1,
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'taxonomy' => 'category'
);

$categories = get_categories($args);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $option = '<option value="/category/archives/'.$category->category_nicename.'">';
    $option .= $category->cat_name;
    $option .= ' ('.$category->category_count.')';
    $option .= '</option>';
    echo $option;
}
```

You can read more about it here for other params: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories